# What to do after a scp failure?

Tags: unix, file-transfer

During a massive 10 hour `scp` over the internet, I ran out of disk space at the destination after 7 hours.

Can I use `rsync` or something else to run this to completion or am I ****ed and have to start all over again?

If I have to start over, I think I will use `rsync` in case the ISP craps out this time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rsync --partial --progress --rsh=ssh $file_source $user@$host:$destination_file
```

or

```
rsync --partial --progress --rsh=ssh $user@$host:$remote_file $destination_file
```